# TSQL to CAML Where value IN OTHER 2010 SP list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, caml, csom

After much research, I can't seem to find a CAML equivalent of

```
SELECT i.Name, i.SubmitDate
FROM issues i 
WHERE i.ServerName IN (
    SELECT s.Name
    FROM servers s 
    WHERE s.Active = true
)
```

Or

```
SELECT i.Name, i.SubmitDate
FROM issues i 
INNER JOIN servers s ON s.Name = i.ServerName
WHERE s.Active = true
```

This is what I have so far.  I've tried `<Includes>` and `<In>` but I can't seem to get the syntax.  Or maybe I  approaching this wrong.  **I can't use LINQ either as i need to pass the CAML query into the SharePoint client object model**  Any ideas?

```
<Query>

<Where>
<Includes>
<FieldRef Name="Name" />
<Value Type="Lookup" />
</Includes>
</Where>

<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Name" />
<FieldRef Name="SubmitDate" />
</ViewFields>

</Query>
```

Comment: The obvious one, two CAML queries, first you get all the values from the inner query and create another query with a big OR (more efficient that multiple independent queries).

Comment: @SJuan76 the issue would be that I am still getting all of the issues back from the server, when if i pass in a CAML query, i only retrieve back the filtered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you object to the original query and I don't know CAML. But this query should be equivalent:

```
SELECT i.Name, i.SubmitDate
FROM issues i INNER JOIN servers s ON s.Name = ServerName
WHERE s.Active = true
```

Comment: Also I personally don't object to using IN but isn't there A bit of a performance hit when you get into larger record amounts compare to a Inner join

Comment: `IN` often results in an identical plan. And actually it's often faster because it's easy to short-circuit once you determine whether something is in the list. A regular join on the other hand requires it to build all the rows in the cross product.